# Hive text table prepared by vi

Tags: sql, hadoop, vim, hive, delimiter

I am following the example on "Programming Hive" to read information from a text file into a table. The table contains 5 columns, with delimiter "^A" (defined by '/001' in Hive). I realized that "^A" is "ctrl-A" in the text, and found some instruction to type "ctrl-A" in vi -- to use "ctrl-V" + "A". Now the text file looks like the attached image.

But when I load the data and insert it into my table, the values cannot be separated (all the values come to the first key -- name, and values for other keys are all NULL).

Anybody has idea about this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `ctrl-v` `ctrl-a` or `ctrl-v` `A`?

Comment: ctrl-v A. ctrl-v ctrl-a give me 2 octal like "octal octal" which looks strange to me.

Comment: Has been fixed. I used macbook "command" key instead of "ctrl" ... Should be "ctrl-v" + "ctrl-a"

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer then so this question can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>.

Also note that <kbd>⌘</kbd> is different to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.